# NLog - Parameter for File Target FileName

Tags: c#, nlog

I am using NLog in a .NET application. Currently, my config section in my App.config looks like this:

```
<nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="assemblyLogFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}/assembly.log" createDirs="true" keepFileOpen="true" encoding="utf-8" layout="${longdate} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}"></target>
    <target name="appLogFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/app.log" createDirs="true" keepFileOpen="true" encoding="utf-8" layout="${longdate} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}"></target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="Assembly" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="assemblyLogFile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="appLogFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

My app is dynamically loading the assemblies. I would like to log each assemblies logs to their own file. In essence, I would like to update the `filename` attribute on the `target` element to something like this:

```
fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}/assembly.[Name].log"
```

In this pattern, "[Name]" is defined in the code. My question is, is there a way to programmatically pass a variable to a target via NLog? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to be completely dynamic, I think you have two approaches.

1) Create a custom log factory and wrapper for `NLog.ILogger` that keeps track of  and injects the assembly name into the NLog logEvent. This means all assemblies must use your logger factory, and not NLog directly.

2) Create a NLog extension that lets you access the assembly name as a layout variable, derived from the logger name. This works if you use the default `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` in all the assemblies.

Here is a naive caching renderer that uses reflection to find the correct assembly. You could probably make this more efficient by scanning assemblies when you load them - or maybe just do string wrangling on the logger name.

```
[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer("assemblyName")]
public class AssemblyNameLayoutRenderer : NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer
{
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> loggerNameToAssemblyNameCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var fullClassName = logEvent.LoggerName;
        var assemblyName = FindAssemblyNameFromClassName(fullClassName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assemblyName))
            builder.Append(assemblyName);
    }

    private string FindAssemblyNameFromClassName(string fullClassName)
    {
        return loggerNameToAssemblyNameCache.GetOrAdd(fullClassName, cl =>
        {
            var klass = (
                from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                from t in a.GetTypes()
                where t.FullName == fullClassName
                select t).FirstOrDefault();

            return klass?.Assembly.GetName().Name;
        });
    }
}
```

And then use this in the config file like this:

```
<extensions>
  <add assembly="AssemblyContainingCustomRenderer" />
</extensions>

<targets>
  <target xsi:type="FilteringWrapper" name="assemblyLogFile" condition="'${assemblyName}' != ''">
    <target name="realAssemblyLogFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs/${shortdate}/assembly.${assemblyName}.log" createDirs="true" keepFileOpen="true" encoding="utf-8" layout="${longdate} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}" /
  </target>  
</targets>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the assembly being loaded creates the logger using `NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("assemblyName")`, then you can do this (Works best with NLog ver. 4.5 or higher):

```
<nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="assemblyLogFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}/${logger}.log" createDirs="true" keepFileOpen="true" encoding="utf-8" layout="${longdate} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}"></target>
    <target name="appLogFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/app.log" createDirs="true" keepFileOpen="true" encoding="utf-8" layout="${longdate} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}"></target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="AssemblyName" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="assemblyLogFile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="appLogFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```